# Did I use the wrong flag?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15465112/2483138) with a custom flag and the text "This is pretty much a link-only answer. The code sample only gives syntax, not any meaningful use of the functionality."  I stand by that synopsis, but the flag was rejected.

Looking at the flag options, it looks like I was supposed to use Not-An-Answer instead.  Is that the appropriate flag for a link-only answer?

Comment: What do you want us to do with it?  Your flag told us that you had an issue with it, but not what we should do. Also, it's got 29 upvotes; what would you have us do? Delete it? Finally, an answer consisting of a link is not necessarily an issue. This one not only has a link, it also has code.  This question can certainly be edited to be better; but looking at it, I'm not sure what you'd want us to do.  In your flag, tell us: What's wrong, what you want us to do, and why.

Comment: a) Yes, I would have you delete it.  I wasn't aware there were other reasons for flagging.  In earnest, I don't know what else I would use it for.
b) Is popularity a measure of correctness?
c) While I acknowledge that there is syntactically correct ruby in that answer, does it help you understand how to use the functionality in question any better than before you read it?  I _know_ how to use it and it doesn't help me.
d) Is a more appropriate course of action to edit the answer to better answer the question?  Then, I'm just writing my own answer under another user's name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you didn't use the wrong flag; you shouldn't have flagged at all.

You should always raise a flag **when you see a problem that you can't address yourself**. In this scenario, you should then choose the flagging option that best describes the problem; if none exists, you should then choose "other" and describe the problem yourself.

But you didn't describe a problem here. You made an observation as to the usefulness of the answer. That's different. A moderator reading that might nod sagely while sipping his tea and grunt in recognition of your observational skills, but... At that point he's pretty much left with nothing to do; there's no problem to be solved, **[no exception to handle](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)**.  If you didn't think the answer was useful, you already had the tools to handle that yourself:

[image: the image of a downvote button]

For a more in-depth look at evaluating answers, check out my guide to differentiating between things that are apples and things that are not: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)