# Is this question good for Low Quality Post review audit?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Today while reviewing the Low Quality Posts review queue, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8526707) audit. I passed the audit as I make sure to check the actual post for almost every review item. Personally I think this post can be assumed as a low quality post as its mostly a link only answer and I think this shouldn't be used as an audit. Please share your thoughts about it?

Answer (score 2):

It's a perfectly fine, though admittedly quite brief, answer.
Whether more detail would be a good idea? Sure, but it has enough to stay.

Nothing link-only or vlq about it, and it is presented as a "known-good" audit, so it's fine.

Recommended reading: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: I agree its a decent answer but it being presented as "known-good" audit is want concerns me.

Comment: It's properly "known good", that doesn't mean it's a good answer, it just means it does not belong deleted. Are you already done reading Shog9's post? In less words about a declined flag: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284819/did-i-use-the-wrong-flag

Answer (score -5):

I agree, he should have explained the two api calls.